# How to increase length of rules?

Tags: tables, booktabs

Is there a way to increase the length of my rules using \toprule, \bottomrule, and \midrule? I want them to extend past the text on both sides of the table a little bit.

Here's my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\toprule 
\emph{X} & \emph{Y} \\
\midrule 
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: a quick solution is changing `{lc}` to something like `{@{~~~}lc@{~~~}}`.

Comment: Welcome! They already do extend a bit to the left and right. How much more extension do you wish? Off-topic: do not use `h` as the sole location option for a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the space between columns using the `@{<stuff>}` column specification, where `<stuff>` could be `\hspace{<len>}` for a specific length. Using these on the outer columns you can make the horizontal rules extend out horizontally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l c }
  \toprule 
  \emph{X} & \emph{Y} \\
  \midrule 
  1 & 2\\
  3 & 4\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} l c @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}} }
  \toprule 
  \emph{X} & \emph{Y} \\
  \midrule 
  1 & 2\\
  3 & 4\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```